# Azure data lake store destination connection manager for SSIS - Unable to authenticate to push data

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-active-directory, azure-data-lake

I am trying to connect to the Azure data lake to push data via SSIS.
I am using the Azure AD user identity method to authenticate but when I click on Test Connection it gives me an error and asks for owner rights on the account. Any particular rights I am missing on the account ?

Comment: It's impossible for us to know what's missing unless we know what's there: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

It's suggested that you use [service principal authentication/service identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-authenticate-using-active-directory) instead of [end-user authentication/user identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-end-user-authenticate-using-active-directory) you are currently using. You will avoid a lot of hassles this way. By design, they serve as non-interactive and interactive authentication methods. The only reason end-user authentication is supported in SSIS is that at the time the ADLS support was being developed, only end-user authentication was finished on ADLS.

For backward compatibility, we continue to support end-user authentication. There is a two-step workflow to follow.

1. For the very first time, user interaction is needed. Upon attempting to connect to ADLS, a dialog will pop up for you to grant permission to SSIS to access ADLS on your behalf.
2. In later runs, user interaction is not needed. Authentication completes silently.